# Deriving a new variables with arrays in R

Tags: r

Consider that we have the data frame as below and it generates a dataset, now i want to derive a new variable MPDFL based on these variables 'MPD1FL','MPD2FL','MPD3FL'. So if any of these variable have Y then MPDFL should have Y else N.

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   MPD1FL=c('N','Y','Y','N','N','N'),
                   MPD2FL=c('Y','N','N','Y','N','N'),
                   MPD3FL=c('N','N','N','Y','N','Y'))

ID  MPD1FL  MPD2FL  MPD3FL
<dbl>   <fct>   <fct>   <fct>
1   N   Y   N
2   Y   N   N
3   Y   N   N
4   N   Y   Y
5   N   N   N
6   N   N   Y
```

I tried the code something as below and it did not work, appreciate your help with R code

```
val <- c('MPD1FL','MPD2FL','MPD3FL')
for (val in val) {
    data2 <- data %>% mutate(MPDFL=if_else(val=='Y','Y','N'))
}

data2
```

Thanks,

Jags

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```
data2 <- data
data2$MPDFL <- c("N", "Y")[(rowSums(data[-1] == "Y") > 0L) + 1L]

data2
#  ID MPD1FL MPD2FL MPD3FL MPDFL
#1  1      N      Y      N     Y
#2  2      Y      N      N     Y
#3  3      Y      N      N     Y
#4  4      N      Y      Y     Y
#5  5      N      N      N     N
#6  6      N      N      Y     Y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
attach(data)
library(dplyr)
data$MPDFL<-case_when(data$MPD1FL=='Y'|data$MPD2FL=='Y'|data$MPD3FL=='Y'~'Y', TRUE~'N')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a `for` loop, albeit this is less efficient than other posted answers for sure:

```
MPDFL <- vector("character", length = nrow(data))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if("Y" %in% data[i, 2:4]) {
    MPDFL[i] <- "Y"
  } else {
    MPDFL[i] <- "N"
  }
}
cbind(data, MPDFL)

  ID MPD1FL MPD2FL MPD3FL MPDFL
1  1      N      Y      N     Y
2  2      Y      N      N     Y
3  3      Y      N      N     Y
4  4      N      Y      Y     Y
5  5      N      N      N     N
6  6      N      N      Y     Y
```